# SQL Stored Procedure - Returning different data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table of different columns of different data types: `nvarchar (ISIN)`, `date (maturity)`, `float (Coupon)`,`int (IssuerID)`.
I have written a stored procedure to return whatever column I input.
However, because the return data type is different, ***SQL*** cannot compile.
Is there a way to get around the issue?

***Code below:***

```
Create procedure dbo.GetBondDes
    @BondID int,
    @BondDes nvarchar(50)
As  
    Select 
    (
    Case
        When @BondDes = 'IssuerID' Then Bonds.IssuerID
        When @BondDes = 'ISIN' Then Bonds.ISIN
        When @BondDes = 'Coupon' Then Bonds.Coupon
        When @BondDes = 'Maturity' Then Bonds.Maturity
    End) 
    From dbo.Bonds
    Where dbo.Bonds.BondID = @BondID
```

Comment: Return all values and let the caller decide which value he needs

Comment: I agree with @user743414, I see little or no point in only return 1 item when they are all columns in the same table. If you really do only want to return one of the 4, then still use 4 columns, but use 4 case expressions to remove unwanted data and return `NULL` instead e.g. `CASE WHEN @BondDes = 'IssuerID THEN Bonds.IssuerID END AS IssuerID, ...` This could be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361) though, might be worth giving some background as to why you only want to return one value each time?

Comment: I am trying to allow the caller to retrieve a specific field

Comment: @TimothyLi I understand what you are trying to do, what I meant was why? What do you gain by only giving the caller one of these fields, and not all 4, then letting them decide how to use the 4? You can convert them all to the same data type, but then your caller would lose any type information, and need to convert them back, potentially incorrectly. So what you want to do is possible, but it is almost certainly not the correct solution to your problem.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for the feedback. After some thoughts, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you will have with your current approach is that you will lose all your type safety, you would need to have a set of rules to define the formats, then have your caller convert back based on the column required.

This is cumbersome and risks data loss. I would suggest simply returning all 4 columns, then letting the caller decide how to use the output.

```
Create procedure dbo.GetBondDes
    @BondID int
As  
    Select Bonds.IssuerID,
            Bonds.ISIN,
            Bonds.Coupon,
            Bonds.Maturity
    From    dbo.Bonds
    Where   dbo.Bonds.BondID = @BondID;
```

If for whatever reason you wanted to mask redundant data you could use:

```
Create procedure dbo.GetBondDes
    @BondID int,
    @BondDes nvarchar(50)
As  
    Select  IssuerID = CASE WHEN @BondDes = 'IssuerID' THEN Bonds.IssuerID
            ISIN = CASE WHEN @BondDes = 'ISIN' THEN Bonds.ISIN
            Coupon = CASE WHEN @BondDes = 'Coupon' THEN Bonds.Coupon
            Maturity = CASE WHEN @BondDes = 'Maturity' THEN Bonds.Maturity
    From    dbo.Bonds
    Where   dbo.Bonds.BondID = @BondID;
```

This would ensure `NULL` is returned for any unnessecary columns (although assuming `BondID` is the primary key this offers no performance advantage over the first option).

Finally, if you *really* do want only a single value returned, you could maintain the original type by using an `IF/ELSE` flow:

```
Create procedure dbo.GetBondDes
    @BondID int,
    @BondDes nvarchar(50)
As  
    IF @BondDes = 'IssuerID'
    BEGIN
        SELECT  IssuerID AS Value
        FROM    dbo.Bonds
        WHERE   BondID = @BondID ;
    END
    ELSE IF @BondDes = 'ISIN'
    BEGIN
        SELECT  ISIN AS Value
        FROM    dbo.Bonds
        WHERE   BondID = @BondID ;
    END
    ELSE IF @BondDes = 'Coupon'
    BEGIN
        SELECT  Coupon AS Value
        FROM    dbo.Bonds
        WHERE   BondID = @BondID ;
    END
    ELSE IF IF @BondDes = 'Maturity'
    BEGIN
        SELECT  Maturity AS Value
        FROM    dbo.Bonds
        WHERE   BondID = @BondID ;
    END
```

Or, you could use dynamic SQL, but I would advise to use this with extreme caution:

```
Create procedure dbo.GetBondDes
    @BondID int,
    @BondDes nvarchar(50)
As  
BEGIN
    -- CHECK COLUMN EXISTS FIRST
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM syy.columns c WHERE c.Name = @BondDes AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Bonds', 'U'))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT ', QUOTENAME(@BondDes), '  AS Value FROM dbo.Bonds WHERE BondID = @BondID');

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@BondID INT', @BondID;
    END
END
```

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you for all your insightful support.

Answer (score 2):

You need a type conversion with `case` expression, however, `concat()` would do what you want :

```
select b.BondID, 
       concat(case when @BondDes = 'IssuerID' then b.IssuerID end,
              case when @BondDes = 'ISIN' then b.ISIN end,
              case when @BondDes = 'Coupon' then b.Coupon end,
              case when @BondDes = 'Maturity' then b.Maturity end
             ) as cols
from dbo.Bonds b 
where b.BondID = @BondID;
```

Comment: This works because `concat()` ignores `NULL` values (rather than returning `NULL`).  That said, you might want to have explicit type conversion to control the format of the results -- particularly for dates.